# Using the SUMMARIZE function in a MAXX calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image]

I am trying to aggregate the following values (NHS, Social Care and Both B) by the  reasons for delays column so i can find the reason with the highest value (from the 3 combined values named above).

I have tried using `summarize` to create a table with just the reasons for delays ,NHS, Social Care and Both B columns. By doing this i hoped i could create a column named totals which adds the NHS, Social Care and Both B Columns together in this summarized table thus giving me the total values for each reason for delay.

Though when i tried to run a maxx function around my totals column it seems to give me the wrong values.

I have tried wrapping my table with the distinct function so it aggregates all the columns in my summarize together, but this did not help either.

```
Max Delays =
MAXX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        csv,
        csv[Reason For Delay],
        csv[NHS],
        csv[Social Care],
        csv[Both B],
        "totals", CALCULATE ( SUM ( csv[NHS] ) + SUM ( csv[Both B] ) + SUM ( csv[Social Care] ) )
    ),
    [totals]
)
```

The smaller table (which should represent the summarized table) in the above picture with the total column shows the values i expect to carry my max calculation over, where i expect the max value to be 277.

The max value i am getting instead is 182. This is the max value in the unsummarized table below where i have multiple duplicates of my reasons for delay column and 182 is the highest value.

I have uploaded a sample of the pbix file i am working on if it may be of help;https://www.zeta-uploader.com/en/1184250523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a measure for total reasons:

```
Total Reasons = SUM(csv[NHS]) + SUM(csv[Both B]) + SUM(csv[Social Care])
```

Second, create a measure for the max reason:

```
Max Reason = MAXX( VALUES(csv[Reason For Delay]), [Total Reasons])
```

Result:

[image]

How it works:

- The first measure is for convenience. You can re-use it in other formulas, making code cleaner;
- In the second measure, we create a list of distinct reasons using VALUES. Then MAXX iterates this list, calculates total for each reason, and then finds the largest of them.

Comment: Could you help me understand why my attempt using summarize and maxx did not work?

Comment: Because you summarized by too many fields, and as a result summarized records where identical to the original records (i.e, if you count rows in your "summarize" table, you will see that it's the same as the number of rows in the underlying csv table).

Comment: I was under the impression wrapping the summarize table i made had only the reasons column and the values i needed. How did the extra fields get included?

I also added a distinct around my table in my summarize but this did not seem to help either

Comment: I re-formatted your formula in the question, take a look. The "Summarize" part says: take table "csv",  group it by [Reason For Delay], [NHS], [Social Care], [Both B], and then add a calculated column "totals" for each resulting record.

Comment: I completely understand that part because i expect the reason for delay column to include all it's duplicates as it does in the original table, though when i added in a distinct csv so that it only brings in the unique values for the reasons for delay column, nothing happened, i got the same results.
Not to mention the column which leads to multiple duplicates of the reasons for delay column is the provider org code or provider org name, but this was not included in my summarize table therefore my summarize table should have been identicle to the first table in the picture i posted.

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure I understand the "distinct csv" part. If you post the formula and explain the idea beihnd it, I'll explain why it's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194052/discussion-between-kvotheslute-and-rado).